# Basic questions about descriptive complexity

Tags: reference-request, logic, computational-complexity, descriptive-complexity

I'm trying to learn descriptive complexity, and I'm having trouble on a basic level wrapping my head around what it means for a logical formula to define a computational language.  I've tried and failed to find a gentle introduction to the field online, but I'd be appreciative if someone could point me towards one.

Let's take a super basic example.  Let's say take the formula $\forall x \, \exists y \, \lnot R(x, y)$.  Questions:

1. Is the definition of $R$ an intrinsic part of the formula, or is it specified by the "input string" given to the formula?  Can $R$ be anything?  Does the statement $R(x, y)$ need to be computationally efficient to check?
2. I have read that the input string is a representation of a "universe," which contains three pieces: a list of "objects" $\{0, \dots, n-1\}$, a set of relation symbols $\{R_1, \dots, R_m\}$, and a set of constant symbols $\{c_1, \dots, c_k\}$.  Why are these useful?  Aren't the relation and constant symbols already specified in the formula to which the input string is provided?

Apologies if these are basic questions - my understanding is currently very poor.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: Most of my questions were answered by these gentle slides: http://msor.victoria.ac.nz/foswiki/pub/Events/ALC2011/LectureSlides/Chen_Yijia.pdf